# Drag and Drop not working in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, drag-and-drop, visual-studio-extensions

I have a TabControl in the extension and I want to change the position of the tabs by dragging them with the mouse. But I ran into the fact that drag and drop just don't work. In debug mode, the mouse pointer always shows the icon of inability to insert, and in release mode, nothing is displayed at all, that is, dragging does not even start. But the same code works in a regular application without problems.

Code:

```xml
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove" />
            <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop" />
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Test 1" />
    <TabItem Header="Test 2" />
    <TabItem Header="Test 3" />
    <TabItem Header="Test 4" />
    <TabItem Header="Test 5" />
</TabControl>
```

```cs
private void TabItem_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(DragDrop.DoDragDrop((TabItem)sender, new DataObject("TestString"), DragDropEffects.All));
    }
}

private void TabItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Data.GetData(typeof(string)));
}
```

Checked in Visual Studio 2015, 2019 Community.

Is there anything I can do about this or will I have to reinvent the wheel with tracking which element the mouse is currently hovering over?

Comment: Could you please share a whole sample with us?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Hello! I added a new window to the extension where I placed the TabControl. https://gitlab.com/phoenix.bars/vsix-test-tabcontrol/

Comment: I renamed the account, so the link is different now: https://gitlab.com/snowy_owl/vsix-test-tabcontrol